# IBM Notes on Windows 8 and UAC

Tags: windows-8, lotus-notes

All applications in Windows 8 (incl IBM Notes ) no longer run as administrator by default.

I recently discovered that if Notes is not run as administrator the provisioning install is not working

According to a [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21615390) on IBM an UAC prompt should appear during provisoning install but my users are not getting the uac prompt, instead they are presented with a provisioning fail prompt.

UAC level is set as the lowest level, (Never Notify)

If I set IBM Notes as Adminstrator from the shortcut it works, but this is not something users understand.

What do I need to do to allow my users to do provisioning install?

My users are using IBM Notes 9.0.1

For one of my users we started Notes as administrator and installed a dictionary plugin and after that we could start notes (not as administrator) and it was working fine. (probably domain admin)

For another user we have to set the shortcut to always run as administrator or Notes will not start at all after the dictionary install.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft claims that never notify automatically declines all UAC prompts

> If you're signed with a standard user account, any changes that
>   require administrator permissions will automatically be denied.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-user-account-control-settings#1TC=windows-8

The IBM technote says a security prompt, but not specifically a UAC prompt. I suspect it's meant to be an installer prompt telling you it failed, not a UAC elevation prompt, like your question seems to suppose.

> By default all Applications run at "Medium Integrity level” in Windows
>   8 if you disable UAC. **Elevate to high level to run successfully.**